# GCC compile type error: expected type-specifier

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

I've the following source code, compiled with MinGW. But when I try to build I've a compile type error:

```
main.cpp:11: error: expected type-specifier
   using Iter = MyMap::iterator;
              ^
main.cpp:12: error: expected type-specifier
   using CIter = MyMap::const_iterator;
               ^
```

GCC expect a specifier before `MyMap`. But which specifier does it expect?

```
#include <ctime>
#include <map>

template< typename T >
class MyClass
{
private:
    class Inner {};

    using MyMap = std::map< time_t, Inner >;
    using Iter = MyMap::iterator;
    using CIter = MyMap::const_iterator;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to read [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords/613132#613132).

Comment: thank you very much. I'll read it careful

Comment: I have the impression this problem pops up several times per day on SO. Yet, I failed to find a good duplicate. Perhaps this is because the symptoms can be quite different (and the symptoms are what the question title is all about)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just need to add `typename`:

```
using Iter = typename MyMap::iterator;
```

otherwise the compiler doesn't know that `::iterator` refers to a type and not a member variable or method.

Comment: You just saved me possibly hours of debugging!